# Finding the powerset of a String

Tags: java, string, substring, powerset

I'm trying to write a java method for finding the subset of a string but I keep getting a runtime error I have been unable to debug. Here is the code:

```
public static List<String> subset(String m, List<String> list){
    if (m.length() <= 1){
        list.add(m);
        return list;
    }
    else{
        String letter = m.substring(0,1);
        String rest = m.substring(1,m.length());
        for (String x : subset(rest,list)){
            list.add(letter + x);

        }

        list.add(letter);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 3) There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: You may find [this article](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_Set) informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in your `for` loop, you're iterating through a list that's constantly changing.  This gives you a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

It's better if you make a copy of your list first, before you try to iterate through it.  You want something like this in place of your `for` loop.

```
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(subset(rest,list));
for (String x : copy){
   list.add(letter + x);
}
```

This works, of course (yes, I've tested it), but it's a bit confusing in the way that you've added SOME elements by recursion and OTHERS by iteration.  I think a re-design would be a good idea.

Comment: I am using recursion to break down the problem and iteration to tie it back up. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve the solution or a better approach? Thanks

Comment: No, really, that's not what you're doing at all.  At each level of the recursion, half of the power set gets built by passing your existing list into the call to `subset`, and the other half gets built inside the `for` loop.  For consistency, I would NOT pass the existing list into `subset`, then I would add two elements, not just one, in each iteration of the `for` loop.